# Python Explain if key(arg) < key(ans)

Tags: python-3.x

```
def min(*args, **kwargs):
    key = kwargs.get("key", None)
    if len(args) == 1: 
        vars = args[0]
    else: 
        vars = args[:]
    ans = None
    for arg in vars:
        if ans is None:
            ans = arg
            continue
        if key is not None:
            if key(arg) < key(ans):
                ans = arg
        else:
            if arg < ans:
                ans = arg
        return ans

print(min("hello"))
print(min([[1,2], [3, 4], [9, 0]], key=lambda x: x[1]))
```

can someone explain me this part of the above code???

```
for arg in vars:
    if ans is None:
        ans = arg
        continue
    if key is not None:
        if key(arg) < key(ans):
            ans = arg
    else:
        if arg < ans:
            ans = arg
```

Additionally, is there any way to do this using `sorted()` thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's some comments that describe what's going on:

```
# vars represents the items we're attempting to find the minimum of.
# arg is the current item we're considering
for arg in vars:
    # ans is our running minimum value, and it initialized to None. If 
    # it's still None, this is the first arg we've tried, so just update 
    # the running minimum and move on to the next
    if ans is None:
        ans = arg
        continue
    # If a key function was passed, compare the result of passing our 
    # running minimum (ans) through it to the result of passing the 
    # current arg through it
    if key is not None:
        # If the result of the arg is less, make arg our new running 
        # minimum
        if key(arg) < key(ans):
            ans = arg
    # If there was no key function supplied, just compare the values of 
    # the running minimum (ans) and the current arg
    else:
        # If the current arg is smaller, make it the new running minimum
        if arg < ans:
            ans = arg
```

Could you use `sorted`? Sure, pass the `key` if it was provided, and just return the first item in the sorted list. It wouldn't be terribly efficient, though. Sorting the entire list is slower than just taking one pass through to find the minimum.